# Project Server CSOM Local Custom Fields

Tags: c#, sharepoint, csom, ms-project, project-server

I'm writing a .net application where i'm using CSOM (Microsoft.ProjectServer.Client) to connect to a PWA (On-Premise).

I am able to connect to projects, tasks, find enterprise custom fields, ...
However, I can't seem to find any local custom fields for tasks (Text1-Text30, Number1-Number30, ...)

Is there a way to access these through CSOM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not available in CSOM version 15, but is is available in version 16.

Documentation can be found [here](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Project-CSOM-Read-Local-CustomFields)